# I'm trying to do a program to download videos of a playlist with pytube, but it doesnt works

Tags: python, pytube

I'm trying to do a program that downloads the videos of a playlist from youtube, this is the program:

```
from pytube import Playlist
from pytube import YouTube



playlist = Playlist('https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZ1u221jNfYGCxHU4RbChwG60X-_nq8HK')
print('Number of videos in playlist: %s' % len(playlist.video_urls))
for video_url in playlist.video_urls:
f = open (r'D:\Nueva carpeta (4)\lista_viejas.txt','a')
f.write("\n")
f.write(str(video_url))

f.close()

with open(r'D:\Nueva carpeta (4)\lista_viejas.txt', 'r') as file1:
with open(r'D:\Nueva carpeta (4)\lista_viejass.txt', 'r') as file2:
    with open (r'D:\Nueva carpeta (4)\output.txt', "w") as out_file:
        f2_lines = set(file2)
        for line in file1:
            if line not in f2_lines:
                
                yt = YouTube(str(line))
                video = yt.streams.first()
                video.download(r'D:\Nueva carpeta (4)')
                
                out_file.write(line)
                f2_lines.add(line)
```

I dont know why I get this error in this part:

```
Exception has occurred: RegexMatchError
regex_search: could not find match for (?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*
File "C:\Users\Andres\Desktop\Untitled-1.py", line 22, in <module>
yt = YouTube(str(line))



yt = YouTube(str(line))
                video = yt.streams.first()
                video.download(r'D:\Nueva carpeta (4)')
```

If I change the parameter "line" to `line_prove=input()`, it works.

Comment: for starters, your indentation is off

Answer (score 0):

ok i dont know why, but i tried to writte it in another way, and its fix it i just added

```
    YouTube(line).streams.first().download(r'D:\Nueva carpeta (4)'
```